# Using pointers to read and write to a file

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to pointers and I have a task to read a 2d array from a file.
I have to use the function which takes in a parameter (char * path).As you can see i am manually typing in which text file i want to open in the code but i think i have to use pointers as it is the parameter in my 'read_from_file' function. I am taking user inputs at command line to see which file they want to read from using the code below. I'm unsure how to use char* argv[] as parameter that will be passed on to my read_from_file(char *path) so that i can read from the file the user stated. My code for reading from a file works completely fine but i just want some help with the pointers.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
```

---

```
int read_from_file(char *path){



ifstream infile("file.txt");
string line;

std::vector<std::vector<int> > num;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))

{
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::istringstream iss(line);
int value;
while (iss >> value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}

num.push_back(values);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `infile(path)`?

Comment: The args are just `argv[0]` and so on presuming the index is less than `argc`.

Comment: The user at command line are required to enter the file name they want to read from. for example they can type "file.txt. and this argument should be passed onto the read_from_file(char* path) so that it can read the contents of this file into a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want anything fancy:

```
// Note: argv[0] is the name of the program itself, 1..n are actual arguments
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
  read_from_file(argv[i]);
}
```

Then you can use that in your function:

```
std::ifstream infile(path);
```

Typically in C++ you should specify arguments like this as `const char*`.